# Как конвертировать картинку в двоичный код с помощью python?

Tags: python, sql-server, изображения

У меня есть картинка(путь к ней), как мне перевести ее в двоичный код для `mssql`(не хочу передавать в раcширение `Image`) и обратно

Comment: Картинки и так в бинарном формате. Считываете картинку через `open` с режимом `rb` и получите массив байтов

Comment: @gil9red спасибо)

Comment: `dbCursor.execute(sql, params)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=4 param-type=_io.BufferedReader', 'HY105')`
такая ошибка

Comment: В базе данных у поля картинки какой тип? BLOB? Возможно, вам нужно через Binary заполнять запрос: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11847994/5909792

Comment: @gil9red varbinary(MAX) я пользуюсь mssql, у меня есть binary(MAX) и bit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25869725/5909792